# Marketing Cloud - Using SSL After SAP request

Tags: marketing-cloud, sap

I am going to compile the Sender Authentication Package form for my client.
For time reason, we might need to postpone the SSL certificate purchase. Is there any problem (other than the security risk) in compiling the SAP form and then adding the SSL After few months and when needed and required?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- insecure links
- If you set up cloudpages on the SAP domain before SSL and want them
  to be HTTPs, they do not automatically switch. You'll have to
  recreate them once you have SSL.
- I just looked at a system in this limbo state (SAP yes, SSL no) yesterday. Inside SFMC, all http:// images (those uploaded after SAP took effect to image.subdomain.client.com) got blocked. Browser was chrome, did not test others.
  Those images still on the standard, unbranded, but "https://" sfmc subdomain
  worked fine, but that domain is of course no longer available for uploads. Sent emails of course also had the http images and they displayed. But while editing
  emails, you might have to work with "broken image" placeholders, not
  WYSIWYG images until SSL is in in place.

Also when you say SSL, keep in mind you might want two. One for images, one for "everything else".

Comment: Many thanks, Jonas. I didnt get this sentence: "Those images still on the standard, unbranded, but "https://" sfmc subdomain worked fine, but that domain is of course no longer available for uploads." please could u clarify it? Best regards

Comment: if you upload images to the default domain (without sap, so something like "sfmc-content"), SFMC will always host them as https://. Good - Those will display normally. Once you upload images to the SAP domain (the branded one), they become http:// -> those are blocked in my example, until SSL cert for images is purchased. Problem is: Once you have SAP, you can no longer upload images to the sfmc-content domain.